# Symfony 1.4 - How to set default values on sfWidgetFormChoice (checkboxes)

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

The following code creates a field with multiple checkboxes. How do I set the default values of these checkboxes?

```
new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
 "choices" => $choices,
 "label" => "Label",
 "multiple" => true,
 "expanded" => true
));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the defaults manually:

```
$countries = array(
    'Spain',
    'England',
    'France'
);

$this->widgetSchema['countries'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $countries, 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true));

// Form will render with Spain and England pre-selected
$this->widgetSchema['countries']->setDefault(array(0,1));
```

If the object to which the form is related is not new, the defaults will pre-selected based on stored values, so you may need to add a `$this->getObject()->isModified()` check around the last line.

Comment: This specific method did not work, but a workaround made sense: $this->setDefault('countries', array(0,1)) It is also worth noting that 0 and 1 correspond to indices in the $countries array. These indices can also be strings.

Comment: Actually it does work, I tested it before posting code, it just depends on how your widget schema is setup. If you found this answer helpful please accept. Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form which has a widget with select

```
$this->widgetSchema['example_select_export'] =  new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
                                        'multiple' => false,
                                        'expanded' => false,
                                        'choices' => array("csv" => "CSV", "excel" => "Excel", "csv_mac" => "CSV mac")

                                );
$choices = array("csv" => "CSV", "excel" => "Excel", "csv_mac" => "CSV mac");
```

You can either set default in the action where you have created your form call this

```
$this->form->setDefault('example_select_export','csv')
```

Or if you like just order your choices in the order you want them to show